# Searchkick issue with limiting records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am using Searchkick for searching through user records. I want to limit the records returned to a small number 2. The Searchkick seems to be returning results when I set the limit to anything more than 40, but when the limit is lower it returns blank. I'm using the following code:

```
search_params[:limit] = 2
search_params[:where] = where
user_matches = User.search "*", search_params
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
search_params[:limit] = 2
search_params[:where] = where
```

`search_params` is a hash with following format,

```
{limit: 2, where: where}
```

However, as per the [docs](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying), options should be comma separated instead of a hash, try this

```
user_matches = User.search "*", where: search_params[:where], limit: search_params[:limit]
```